# Change Android Studio Default Behavior for Generated Code

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse, when you let the program auto-fill out your code, you could use the tab button to pass through the attributes and out to the end of the line.  i.e. `startActivity(new Intent(this, Breakdown.class));` would cycle the cursor through `this`, `Breakdown.class`, and outside the `)`. In Android Studio, the tab button simply gives you 4 spaces and you have to manually click outside of the generated code.

Does anybody know if there is a setting in Android Studio that will change this default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such setting in Android Studio as of version 1.1.